# Largest product in a series

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

**Problem description:**

The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

*Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?*

> How to Find the Largest product in a Series

**Review 1**

```
def greatest_product(n):
    numbers=[int(value) for value in n]
    result=[reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, islice(numbers, i, i+5), 1) for i in range(len(numbers)-4)]
    return max(result)
```

**Review 2**

```
def greatest_product(s, m=0):
    for i in range(0, len(s)-4):
        m = max(m, prod(map(int,s[i:i+5])))
    return m
```

***My Solution***

This is [my solution](https://github.com/AmirMotefaker/ProjectEuler/edit/main/Problem8.py) for [problem 8 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) using Python:

```
adjacent_length = 13
largest_product = 0

for i in range(0, len(s) - adjacent_length + 1):

    product = 1

    for j in range(i, i + adjacent_length):
        product *= int(s[j: j + 1])

    if product > largest_product:
        largest_product = product
```

***How could my code be improved?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ***Place import names at top of script***

I am sure you know if you copy paste your code into a console as is, it will raise `NameError`s.

Put the following:

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import islice
from math import prod
```

At the top of script.

Your second function is actually quite effictive, but not as effictive as it can be, you made a simple mistake, `max` can return the maximum value of more than two numbers, its arguments can be infinitely many or an iterable.

So it should be written as this:

```py
def greatest_product(s):
    return max(prod(map(int,s[i:i+4])) for i in range(len(s)-4))
```

Then, to generalize it, as you can see, if you need max product of 4 numbers the first number is 4, so if you need max product of 13 numbers the first number should be 13, just pass two arguments to the function:

```py
def greatest_product(s, n=13):
    return max(prod(map(int,s[i:i+n])) for i in range(len(s)-n))
```

Full code:

```py
from math import prod
def greatest_product(s, n=13):
    return max(prod(map(int,s[i:i+n])) for i in range(len(s)-n))
```